# mi Post Request ajax funciona a medias

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post

Estoy programando en `C# .NET` en el `BackEnd` y tengo una función en `JQUERY`, utilizando `AJAX` que realiza un `POST` desde el `FrontEnd`

con la función que detallaré se genera un `PDF` en el código de `C#` y luego este retorna el `string` en `base64` para ser descargado

el objeto `Datos[0]` contiene diferente información dependiendo la línea que seleccione de una tabla en donde se visualiza la información (`FrontEnd`). Lo que me genera "choque" es que si selecciono ciertas líneas de la tabla, este `post` falla, pero con otras líneas lo hace sin ningún problema descargando el archivo.

cuando genera el problema, le hago seguimiento por el `devtools` del explorador ya que ni siquiera llega a comunicarse con la función del `BackEnd`, y revisando los datos que se envían, no le falta ninguno sin mencionar que están correctos (ya que fallaría con los demás registros)

el error es este obtenido desde el `devtools`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el error obtenido en la `console` del `devtools`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí mi código del post:

```
$.ajax({
                                    type: "post",
                                    url: URL,
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    data: {
                                        'Solicitante': Datos[0]["Rut"],
                                        'GradoSolicitante': Datos[0]["Grado"],
                                        'Departamento': Datos[0]["Departamento"],
                                        'FecSolicitud': Datos[0]["Fecha de Emisión"],
                                        'Nombre': Datos[0]["Solicitante"],
                                        'Contacto': Datos[0]["Contacto"],
                                        'FecIni': Datos[0]["Fecha de Inicio"],
                                        'FecTerm': Datos[0]["Fecha de Término"],
                                        'Horarios': Datos[0]["Horarios"],
                                        'TotalDias': parseFloat(Datos[0]["DiasPendientes"]),
                                        'NombreReemplazo': Datos[0]["Reemplazo"],
                                        'NombreFirma': Datos[0]["FirmaSolicitud"],
                                        'Grado': Datos[0]["GradoFirmaSolicitud"],
                                        'cargoFirma': CargoFirma,
                                        'Periodo': parseInt(Año),
                                    },
                                    success: function (r) {
                                        Resultados.push(true);
                                        var a = $("<a />");
                                        a.attr("download", "A1-Solicitud " + Tipo + " año " + new Date().getFullYear() + " " + Datos[0]["Solicitante"] + "-" + new Date().getTime());
                                        a.attr("href", r.file);
                                        $("body").append(a);
                                        a[0].click();
                                        $("body").remove(a);
                                    }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                        console.log(xhr.responseText, status, error);
                                    }
                                }),
```

y el código de `C#` que recibe el `POST` (más que nada lo adjunto para que se vea que los parámetros enviados son los correctos):

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImprimirPA(string Solicitante, string GradoSolicitante, string Departamento, string FecSolicitud,
        string Nombre, string Contacto, string FecIni, string FecTerm, string Horarios, double TotalDias, string NombreReemplazo,
        string NombreFirma, string Grado, string cargoFirma, int Periodo)
    { mi código interno }
```

si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradezco de antemano ya que llevo dándole vueltas varios días y no he conseguido solucionarlo

Comment: ¿no tienes acceso al log de errores del servidor donde estás accediendo?  Allí verás información ampliada del error 500 y podrás encontrar mejor el error

Comment: el servidor es literalmente el localhost ya que estoy utilizando visual studio, pero al realizar el post y obtener el error 500 ni siquiera logra entrar a la función de c# ya que le tengo puesto el debugger para ver los datos que entran

Comment: Un error 500 puede ser por algo tan simple como un carácter de más o de menos hasta algo más grave. Como dice @masterguru, deberías revisar el log de errores del servidor que procesa la llamada a Ajax, o, si no tienes posibilidad de revisarlo, mostrar el fragmento de código con el que manejas la petición.

Comment: SOLUCIONADO.... activando el ´<customErrors mode="Off" />´ me aparece que el parámetro "TotalDias" recibe un null, pero al hacer un alert(Datos[0]["TotalDias"]) si muestra un valor.... que es (2.5), cambié el parámetro a string y le hice un replace "," por "." y en c# lo convertí a double, logrando imprimir el reporte sin problemas

Comment: lo que me llama la atención es por que si desde jquery envío parseFloat(2.5) en c# double TotalDias no lo recepciona y lo marca como null